# Extracting multiple zipped JSON files in-memory and saving them to Azure Blob Storage with Python

Tags: python, azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I have a function that communicates with a SOAP API, receives binaries and ultimately extracts a small number of JSON files that I wish to save to an Azure Blob Storage Container using Python.

The official Microsoft documentation and examples are useful for saving a single file, but when I try to do the same for multiple files I get an error code:

**TypeError: Blob data should be of type bytes.**

See below for the code cell and error code.

```
# Extract Pre Survey JSON responses from binaries and send to Azure Blob storage:

import os
import io, zipfile
from io import BytesIO
from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient, BlobClient, ContainerClient, __version__
from functools import reduce

blob = BlobClient.from_connection_string(conn_str="connection string", container_name="container name", blob_name=name)

local_path = "./temp"

def temp_extract():
  for i in binaries: ---> N.B from previous cell.  
    with zipfile.ZipFile(io.BytesIO(i)) as zfile: 
      for name in zfile.namelist():
        if name.endswith('.json'):
          zfile.extract(name, local_path)

def  upload_blobs():
  upload_file_path = os.path.join(local_path, name)
  onlyfiles = reduce(lambda x,y : x+y, [map(lambda x: root + "/" + x, files) for root, dirs, files in os.walk(local_path)])
  onlyfiles = [file for file in onlyfiles if file.endswith('.json')]
  for file in onlyfiles:
      print(os.path.getsize(file))
      with open(file, 'r') as f:
        blob.upload_blob(data = f, overwrite=True)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    temp_extract()
    upload_blobs()
```

I get the following error code:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-273-fb49f396fab5> in <module>
     26 if __name__ == '__main__':
     27     temp_extract()
---> 28     upload_blobs()
     29 

<ipython-input-273-fb49f396fab5> in upload_blobs()
     22       print(os.path.getsize(file))
     23       with open(file, 'r') as f:
---> 24         blob.upload_blob(data = f, overwrite=True)
     25 
     26 if __name__ == '__main__':

~/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/azure/core/tracing/decorator.py in wrapper_use_tracer(*args, **kwargs)
     81             span_impl_type = settings.tracing_implementation()
     82             if span_impl_type is None:
---> 83                 return func(*args, **kwargs)
     84 
     85             # Merge span is parameter is set, but only if no explicit parent are passed

~/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/azure/storage/blob/_blob_client.py in upload_blob(self, data, blob_type, length, metadata, **kwargs)
    683             **kwargs)
    684         if blob_type == BlobType.BlockBlob:
--> 685             return upload_block_blob(**options)
    686         if blob_type == BlobType.PageBlob:
    687             return upload_page_blob(**options)

~/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/azure/storage/blob/_upload_helpers.py in upload_block_blob(client, data, stream, length, overwrite, headers, validate_content, max_concurrency, blob_settings, encryption_options, **kwargs)
     86                 data = data.read(length)
     87                 if not isinstance(data, six.binary_type):
---> 88                     raise TypeError('Blob data should be of type bytes.')
     89             except AttributeError:
     90                 pass

**TypeError: Blob data should be of type bytes.**
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you're getting this error is because you're passing a file object as data to the upload_blob method whereas the method expects the content.

What you would do is read the contents of the file and then pass the file contents to the upload_blob method.

Something like:

```
with open(file, 'r') as f:
    file_content = f.read()  
    blob.upload_blob(data = file_content, overwrite=True)
```

Comment: Thank you for the help. This gets rid of the error code and actually uploads something to the container, but for some reason it only saves one out of three files and uses an incorrect file format and file name - In the previous step (extracting data from the SOAP API) I get three json files and three txt files that describe the aforementioned json files. I get the last json file in the blob but named after one of the txt files that was filtered out using "onlyfiles = [file for file in onlyfiles if file.endswith('.json')]"

Comment: Could it be because you're setting a fixed name of the blob: `blob = BlobClient.from_connection_string(conn_str="connection string", container_name="container name", blob_name=name)`? Can you try creating an instance of BlobClient just before you call upload_blob method and see if that solves your problem?

Comment: Perfect! I am glad to hear that.